# expectation value of steps needed to fill every of $k$ holes

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

I have infinity number of balls and $k$ holes (which have infinity volume). In every step I put one ball to one of holes with probability $\frac{1}{k}$. I stop when there  is at least one ball in every hole. 
What's the expectation value of number of steps till the process stop.
How can I approximate it when $k$ is big?

Comment: How does your step look like? Where is the randomness?

Comment: in every step I put a ball with probability 1/k to one of the k holes

Comment: and in every hole there could be more than 1 ball, but when there is no empty hole we stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking about this as infinity number of balls and k holes. Think of it as you're drawing lots (each numbered from 1 to k), and you want to stop when you have gotten each number in 1 to k at least once.

When represented in this format, it can be seen as a coupon collector problem. The expected value then is the summation of $k / i$ for $i$ ranging from $k$ to $1$.

For an approximation, this is just $k$ times the $k$th harmonic number.

Additional reference for coupon collector problem:
https://brilliant.org/wiki/coupon-collector-problem/